# Custom Post Type Loading 404 Page With Category in the URL

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have set a Custom Post Type using the following code:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpshout_register_major' );
function wpshout_register_major() {
    $args = array(
        'public' => true,
        'label'  => 'Major',
        'has_archive'  => true,
        'rewrite'  => array( 'slug' => '%category%' ),
        'supports' => array( 
            'title',
            'editor',
            'author',
            'thumbnail',
            'excerpt',
            'comments',
            'revisions'
        ),
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'category' )
    );
    register_post_type( 'major', $args );
}
```

Everything works fine, except for the page loading a 404 page.

When the following line is changed to a fixed string, then it works and loads successfully:

```
'rewrite'  => array( 'slug' => 'major' ),
```

But i don't want fixed string in the URL, i want category which is link to the custom post.

Could you please help with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you updated your permalinks under `Settings`->`Permalinks`?

Comment: Yes i did many times.